# internal error while finding XKRN library when running java --version on MacOS

Tags: java, macos

Bit of an unusal one. I am using MacOS 11.5.1 and Java, which I can run fine anywhere on the path - except in the installation directory, which is stopping IntelliJ 2021.2 was being able to run (oddly IntelliJ 2021.1.3 works fine). I can as well if I use `sudo`, so it's something to do with my environment but I'm at a total loss.

For example:

```
java --version
openjdk 15.0.2 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-15.0.2.7.1 (build 15.0.2+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-15.0.2.7.1 (build 15.0.2+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

However if I run from the installation directory:

```
./java --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
internal error while finding XKRN library
internal error while finding XKRN library
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

sudo ./java --version                                                                                                                                                                                                               Password:
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment JBR-11.0.11.9-1504.13-jcef (build 11.0.11+9-b1504.13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JBR-11.0.11.9-1504.13-jcef (build 11.0.11+9-b1504.13, mixed mode)
```

I use `/usr/libexec/bin/java_home` to set JAVA_HOME and the JDKs are installed in the usual place.

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Matching Java Virtual Machines (5):
    15.0.2 (x86_64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 15" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-15.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.12.1 (x86_64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 11" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.12 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 11.0.12" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.12.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.301.09 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_271 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I've tried redownloading and installing new JDKs, with and without JAVA_HOME set but I see the same issue.

Has anyone else ever seen this?

Answer (score 1):

So I used a command to find out what files were accessed when I was running `java --version`.

```
sudo opensnoop -n name
```

This allowed me to find a file I had copied into the `/usr/local/lib/rt/' directory for another application was causing the issues. Removed it and hey presto I'm back in business.